# PHP Mailer with Custom Live Domain (hotmail/outlook)

Tags: php, outlook, live, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail with phpmailer using custom Live domain.

I want to know wether the `$mail->host` and `$mail->Port` I'm using are correct.

The following is the error:

> Mailer Error: The following From address failed: yyy@xxxx.com : Called Mail() without being connected

Here is my code:

```
require("../PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.live.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.live.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I remember PHP Mailer is outdated and is no longer developed/supported, take a look  at [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: That is not an answer, he is not asking about the support of the plugin.